# Upload the images using cloudinary

Tags: swift

If i am using the Following function

```
func onCloudinaryCompletion(successResult:[AnyHashable: Any]?, errorResult:String?, code:Int?, idContext:Any?) {    
    print("Error-\(errorResult)")
    print("Code-\(code)")

    print("successResult-\(successResult)")
    if (successResult != nil)
        {
            let publicURL = successResult?["secure_url"] as! String
            print("now cloudinary uploaded, public url is: \(publicURL), ready for uploading media")
            sendPhotoReport(publicURL)
        }
```

I am getting following output

```
Error-Optional("Invalid Signature 0e791bbbd45acf18cd226688ad9197d560f9ea4d. String to sign - \'timestamp=1476729611\'.")
```

Code-Optional(401)
successResult-nil

So I am not able to upload the image in cloudinary

Comment: This looks like a server error, so you should see what `Invalid Signature` means on your server.

Comment: Hi Dima thanks for your response, what is the reason for getting success result is nil

Comment: I'm assuming because there was an error. You have an `errorResult` instead. It is typical of an API like this to include a success response OR an error. You need to figure out why you're getting an error.

Comment: sorry Dima i cannot find the error.

Comment: Just googling, I found this: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/59

Comment: Ok Dima I will try this URL